# Problem with paths and getting data from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to reach my Details-page for specific Ad on path 'allads/:id' . The page opens but I can't reach the data in my Firebase Database. `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` This is the error from browser. It is the same with Edit-page.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },  
  { path: 'create-ad', component: CreateAdComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'allads', component: AlladsComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'allads/:id', component: DetailsComponent },
  { path: 'edit-ad/:id', component: EditAdComponent }
```

Details html

```
<section id="details-page">
    <article class="details-gage-title">
        <h1>Details Page</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="details-page-card">

        <article class="details-page-card-image">
            <img src="./assets/static/img/man.png" alt="details-image">
        </article>

        <article class="details-page-card-content">
            <p>Author: petar@abv.bg</p>
            <h2>{{ad.headline}}</h2>
            <h3>{{ad.company}}</h3>
            <h4>{{ad.description}}</h4>
            <h5>{{ad.location}}</h5>

            <article class="details-page-card-buttons">
                
                <a href="#" class="btn-edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn-delete">Delete</a>

            </article>
        </article>

    </article>
</section>
```

Details component takes @Input from my Ad interface and that's all there.

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headline')
    at DetailsComponent_Template (details.component.html:13:17)
 ...
...
All paths to core,etc
man.png:1          GET http://localhost:4200/allads/assets/static/img/man.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is link to Repo in GitHub: https://github.com/emustanski/angularproject .
Here is the whole code. It is for exam project.

Comment: The issue isn't with your routes. Please post the full error message and the code for the Details/Edit pages.

Comment: Added more info. Thanks for helping.

Comment: For the Details component, `ad` is undefined which is why you're getting errors in the template. `@Input` is for passing a value from a parent component, not for routing. You might be able to get away with providing a default value depending on your desired outcome. Something like `ad: IAd = { headline: '', ... };`